# javascript join method doesn't work together with another method

Tags: javascript

Trying to add an extra item to the array, and join items.

```
var daysinweek = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

daysinweek.push('funday');
daysinweek.join(', ');

alert(daysinweek);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/n3s9m7L8/

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean something like this

```
var daysinweek = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

daysinweek.push('funday');
var temp =  daysinweek.join(', ');
alert(temp);
```

Without the temp variable:

```
var daysinweek = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

daysinweek.push('funday');
alert(daysinweek.join(', '));
```

Comment: I know I can do it that way, but what if I don't want to involve two different variables?

Comment: @bazzlebrush see my edit

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain why my original code doesn't work? as I'm learning.

Comment: @bazzlebrush - .join() doesn't modify the array and turn it into a string. It just joins the array. If you don't capture that join in a variable, or use it right away - it will be lost. push() on the other hand does modify the array. So some methods modify the array and some don't. It's often defined in a natural way.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine.  Array.join returns a string.  Grab that and alert it rather than the array itself.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join